# Sequelize looking for a mistery column when using a N:M with a transition table - TableTableId

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

We have the following setup. A user, role, and user_role migrations and models files. Please pardon the extra amount of code snippets. Now, this is not exactly an issue as I have found a fix but the fix is more of a bandaid and not quite proper.

The 3 model and migration files are for a N:M relation between User and Role via a User_Roles table. The part that is a problem is this:

When we use  `User.findByPk` like in the following code snipped:

```js
// Donor
isDonor = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findByPk(req.userId).then((user) => {
    user.getRoles().then((roles) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        console.log(roles[i].user_type);
        if (roles[i].user_type === 'donor') {
          next();
          return;
        }
      }
      res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Require Donor Role!',
      });
      return;
    });
  });
};
```

We get this SQL statement and error:

```js
25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'RoleRoleId' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'SELECT `user_id`, `email`, `password`, `bio`, `activity_status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `RoleRoleId` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`user_id` = 3;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'SELECT `user_id`, `email`, `password`, `bio`, `activity_status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `RoleRoleId` FROM 
`Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`user_id` = 3;',
  parameters: {}
}
```

So the Sequalize generated SQL includes a `RoleRoleId` in the columns it's looking for. However, as we see from this image (and the code snippets at the end of this post) no such field exists.

[image]

I have a feeling that perhaps there is a better way to define the relation and table but I am not sure what that would be. I have used the following fix:

```js
User.findByPk(req.userId, {
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['RoleRoleId'],
    },
  })
```

While this works and enables the Server/API to function it feels like a bandaid and not addressing the reason for the issue. Do you have any thoughts? Is the way I am defining the N:M is a transition table incorrectly implemented or perhaps this is an issue with the Sequalize package?

**models** folder

user.model.js

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: 'user_roles',
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        otherKey: 'role_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
      User.hasMany(models.User_Role);

      User.hasMany(models.Address, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });

      User.hasOne(models.Receiver, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      bio: DataTypes.STRING,
      activity_status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

role.model.js

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'user_roles',
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
        otherKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
      Role.hasMany(models.User);
    }
  }
  Role.init(
    {
      role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      user_type: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('donor', 'receiver', 'courier', 'admin'),
        defaultValue: 'courier',
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Role',
    }
  );
  return Role;
};
```

user_role.model.js

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User_Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User_Role.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
      });
      User_Role.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
      });
    }
  }
  User_Role.init(
    {
      user_role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User_Role',
    }
  );
  return User_Role;
};
```

**migrations** folder

1-create-user.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      user_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      bio: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      activity_status: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  },
};
```

3-create-role.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Roles', {
      role_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      user_type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Roles');
  },
};
```

6-create-user_role.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('User_roles', {
      user_role_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'Users', key: 'user_id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      role_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'Roles', key: 'role_id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('User_roles');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question we can use this fix by excluding the column in question. However, this is not a way to address the underlining reason for the issue.

```js
    User.findByPk(req.userId, {
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['RoleRoleId'],
        },
      })
```